# Issue with combining multiple forms into one, using react and redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

In my app i have multiple forms that handle a specific usecase:
- adding pointers
- adding ssl certificates
- ...

These forms are used stand-alone, but sometimes there's the need to combine two or more forms into one.

I've read the wizard example (https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/examples/wizard/) and have applied it to my code. It works succesfully when used as a wizard, when only one form is visible at a time.

But when both forms need to be visible at the same time, i run into problems. When entering data into the 2nd form, the redux-form uses the 1st form for validation.

I hope i can explain it well enough. Here some pseudo code:

```
<Wizard>
        <WizardStep
            title={formatMessage(messages.step1Title)}
            isActive
            step={1}
        >
            <DomainPointerFormContainer
                initialValues={{
                    pointer: pointer && pointer.pointer,
                    domain: application.domain
                }}
            />
        </WizardStep>

        <WizardStep
            title={formatMessage(messages.step2Title)}
            isActive
            step={2}
        >
            <SslCertificateFormContainer
                existingCertificates={existingCertificates}
                onSubmit={submitForm}
                submitLabel={formatMessage(messages.submitLabel)}
                submittingLabel={formatMessage(messages.submittingLabel)}
            />
        </WizardStep>
    </Wizard>
```

DomainPointerFormContainer looks like this:

```
import DomainPointerForm from 'Form/DomainPointerForm';
...
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'wizard',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
    enableReinitialize: true,
})(DomainPointerForm);
```

SslCertificateFormContainer looks like this:

```
import SslCertificateForm, { validate } from 'Form/SslCertificateForm';
...
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'wizard',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validate
})(SslCertificateForm);
```

The validate function looks a lot like in the redux-form examples, so nothing special there.

Is there a way to make this work, or do i have to create a new form that combines the contents of the two separate forms, which leads to a lot of duplication...

Comment: In this case, would it not be easier to leave the state in the DOM and handle the data on submit, the good old fashion HTML5 way (e.g. uncontrolled inputs)? Then you could just render the form "sections" into one form as you need to.

Comment: Have you tried using field-level validations? Seems like you're experiencing some collision with the form-level validation

Comment: Theres field level validation on all inputs of both forms.
But i require some sort of form level validation to validate field combinations. Hence the validate function in the 2nd form